# Can you create a file that you can't access for unit testing to test for a permission error

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am in the process of creating a function that will loop over a large amount of files. However, the function will not have access to all of the files. I have added something to the main part of the function which catches the permission errors. However, I am wanting to create a unit test to test for that so I don't need to run it over the large amount of data.

for the unit test, I am currently using `pytest` and `tmpdir` to generate the temporary files and for unit testing. I am trying to make one of the files I generate result in a permission error but I can't figure out how. I have looked at using `os.chmod(file, ...)` but that can't change the permissions on the file to what I want.

Is there a way to make it so that the when I try to access the file I've made, it throws up a permission error? The section in the function that throws up the permission error is an `os.stat(file)` function.

Edit: In addition, the reason I may not be able to access the files is that they may be in directories that I cannot access. Is there a way to create fake temporary directories with files in but I don't have permission to access the files in the directory?

Comment: Did you try something like `subprocess.call(['sudo', 'chown', ....])` then a `subprocess.call(['sudo', 'chmod', ....])` to force it to be unreadable by you? Also, your not `root` right as might be the case in a container?

Comment: You don’t need any permissions on a **file** to stat it, just `x` on every containing directory.